# Razor DatePicker datetime value

Tags: .net, razor, datepicker, datetimepicker

I'm trying to set a datepicker to 3 months ago from todays date, but not sure how to.

this is the code I have in my view:

```
@Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("StartDate", DateTime.Now, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I couldn't find any documentation for it. Any suggestions?

thanks in advance

Comment: You have there current datetime. How about subtracting three months of it?

Comment: I know I can do it in the backend subtracting the months, but I was wondering if it can be done straight in the view

Comment: This is the view and that's where you'd do it, or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, You were right, I didn't know about .substract() or AddDays() for datetime. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer was easier than I thought and I resolved it with AddDays method

@Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("StartDate", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90), new { @class = "form-control" })